# fluid template: render image only if it exists

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-9.x, fluid-styled-content

How can I use f:if to see if an image exists on the server before trying to render it?

I have tried the following without success:

```
<f:if condition="fileadmin/bilder/Header/{data.title}.jpg">
    <f:then>
        <f:variable name="imageUri" value="fileadmin/bilder/Header/{data.title}.jpg" />
    </f:then>
    <f:else>
        <f:variable name="imageUri" value="fileadmin/bilder/Header/default.jpg" />
    </f:else>
</f:if>
```

{data.title} works correkt. The Problem is that my condition is wrong. It never goes to the else. Probably my condition is interpret as a string und not as an source.

Description here doesn´t help because my Image is on the server.
[Render image in fluid template if it exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58402958/render-image-in-fluid-template-if-it-exists)

Comment: What is the purpose of your check? I guess you look for a header image on a page? Why not putting the image into the page properties and let TYPO3 fetch it easily with TypoScript?

Comment: My first thought was to put the image into the page properties, but I have two possible pictures, one for the header and one for the menu. And it is possible that it exists only one and I cannot differ which picture it is.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, why would you have a hardcoded path to a file in fileadmin in a template? That's very uncommon, most of the time you have some kind of relation through TYPO3 (e.g. through the `media` field in the pages table or something like that).

If this is still something you need, you'd have to write a `FileExistsViewHelper` that checks if the file exists before using it. Here's the documentation on how to write a custom view helper: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/book-extbasefluid/master/en-us/8-Fluid/8-developing-a-custom-viewhelper.html
You'd need to register your filename as an argument with `registerArgument` and then prepend the path to the TYPO3 installation (to make it an absolute path) and check for this file with `file_exists`.
Extend from `\TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\AbstractConditionViewHelper` and implement the `verdict` method.

Your template above just creates a string (as you already guessed).

Comment: If you're using ext:vhs there is a Viewhelper you can use https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/master/Media/ExistsViewHelper.html